# How can I use @Scripts.Render with .Net Core 2.0 MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I use `@Scripts.Render` with a .NET Core 2.0 MVC application?

I am converting code from .NET Framework 4.6.1 to .NET Core 2.0. I have read from **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x)** how to bundle with .NET Core 2.0. How can I fix the error, and replace the code with the new version?

**Code:**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/login")
```

It says

> The name 'Scripts' does not exist in the current context

Existing `BundleConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryvalidate").Include(
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In ASP.Net MVC Core they removed BundleConfig.cs and replaced with bundleconfig.json file. you need to specify your bundle and minification logic in bundleconfig.json. If you don't have this file in your project add  json file with this name.

**bundleconfig.json**

Content of this file should like below.

```
  // Configure bundling and minification for the project.
// More info at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808241
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    // An array of relative input file paths. Globbing patterns supported
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/bundles.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js",
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jqueryvalidate.js"
    ],
    // Optionally specify minification options
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    // Optionally generate .map file
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
 <script src="~/js/bundles.min.js"></script>
```

Read Microsoft docs related to [Bundling and minification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) to get more understanding about Bundling and minification in asp.net core mvc

Comment: This is the link i have added in question

Comment: Oh..  I didn't see the link.. By reading that article you should be able to change the code. Remove the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/login") from _Layout.cshtml and refer your bundle/login.js file directly in script tag

Comment: You also need to move the bundle logic in BunldeConfig.cs to bunldeconfig.js file

Comment: If you add your BundleConfig.cs code to this question then I can help you to change it to bundleconfig.json

Comment: i have added above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163766/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ahamed-ishak).

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the other answer, the `BundleConfig.cs` is gone. However, the `@Scripts.Render()` had some good use cases and it's not a good idea to replace it with static `<script src="..."></script>`. In some cases where you only want to link libraries on some pages, not all, you don't want to repeat the same code over and over especially when you link to the libraries in CDNs with fallbacks. So here is a good approach that I use to replace the old good `@Scripts.Render()`:

First create a partial view for your libraries. You can combine the ones that you use together in the same view if you like. Think about it like you're creating bundles in BundleConfig.cs. For example, you can create a view for the jQuery validation like this:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
</environment>
<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-jR1IKAba71QSQwPRf3TY+RAEovSBBqf4Hyp7Txom+SfpO0RCZPgXbINV+5ncw+Ph">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.10/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator && window.jQuery.validator.unobtrusive"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-y9k3BO+hbWD6gTgtfMyg1egwFmd2oEgQ0fALVtFnCl9F6j6mCh+oCa0P0h+aj7Ii">
    </script>
</environment>
```

You can call it something like `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`.

Now, on the pages where you need the validation, you can inject the partial view like this:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Of course, for those libraries that are required on all pages (like jQuery and Bootstrap), you can inject them directly in `_Layout.cshtml` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_LayoutHeadScriptsPartial")
</head>
<body>
    ...
    @RenderBody()
    ...
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_LayoutFooterScriptsPartial")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a convenient way to determine the hash for the `integrity` attribute?

Comment: @xr280xr Some CDNs have the option to copy the tag with hash. Alternatively, you can use this free tool https://www.srihash.org/.